# Registering PAC Proxy file from Firefox WebExtension - Functions not defined

Tags: firefox, proxy, http-proxy, firefox-addon-webextensions, pac

When I try to register a .pac file from a webextension background script in Firefox using `browser.proxy.register("proxy.pac")`, all the PAC functions expected to be available are not.

Using `isNetName()`, `dnsResolve()`, `shExpMatch()`, etc. all throw an "is not defined" error.

Here is my background script:

```
browser.proxy.register("proxy.pac")
browser.proxy.onProxyError.addListener(error => {
    console.error(`Proxy error: ${error.message}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Browser Extension PAC script [environment is limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/proxy/register#PAC_file_environment) and doesn't support all the functions provided to normal PAC scripts.

Some of those function however can be copied from the [Firefox source code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/5ff2d7683078c96e4b11b8a13674daded935aa44/netwerk/base/ProxyAutoConfig.cpp#32).